# PayPalEnvironmentProduction and PayPalEnvironmentSandbox failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use paypal iOS SDK in out app. I finished registration and create app, then i got two client ID, sandbox and live.

When i use sandbox client ID, live client ID, i got an error.

iOS Alert Tip:

```
We're Sorry. There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers. Please tey again.
```

(I tried many times, but still failed.)

Error Log:

```
PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - System error (PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR). Please try again later. (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: fd805f5f6239a [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.5.0]
```

Please help me.

Thank you~

Comment: PayPal has support channel?

Answer (score 1):

Use only sandbox client id for testing purpose your application

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"AYRzOxBmlQ6vUoUn2O8UHjdYvq9hDdTQ8fE9lfA-glkMJAMYCAaZ"}];

}
```

I use this and its working fine for me..

Comment: IN which os you are running your application...Ios7 or IOS 8?

Comment: I also got issue in IOS 7 and IOS 8

Comment: i am running this application on Ios7